# PostgreSQL query that calculates weekly average backlog and returns

Tags: postgresql

I am stuck with a problem in postgreSQL, I have to calculate weekly average backlog and returns result looking like this (not these numbers, just the structure):

```
week, backlog 
2016-02-01, 5.5 
2016-02-08, 9.2
```

Here, the data is such as a customer pipeline that consists of many stages. We calculate conversion and transition time between each pair of consequent stages which is quite simple, and for some stages we calculate an additional metric which is called the average backlog.
It is a weekly average of daily count of customers that are still waiting to transit to the next stage. High number means there is a bottleneck that should be improved.

Some helpful points:

1. We consider the customer being in a backlog if he doesn't reach stage #2 between 1 and 14 days after reaching stage #1
2. If customer reaches stage #2 on the same day or the next day he never appears in the backlog
3. If customer doesn't reach stage #2 at all he's in the backlog until day 14, then we forget about this customer
4. If customer reaches stage #2 later than 14 days after stage #1 he's appearing in backlog only until day 14 Example: if a customer reached stage 1 on 2017-01-01 and stage 2 on 2017-01-08, he appears in daily backlog on 2017-01-02, 2017-01-03, 2017-01-04, 2017-01-05, 2017-01-06 and 2017-01-07

Here is the link to the data-
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HB7SYOBNy3-hPMkqOaQpmn-k5FeneZBZ/view?usp=sharing

Sample of the Data

```
id  state_1 state_2
1   54:10.7 36:39.1
2   07:09.5 40:57.6
3   20:15.2 54:43.4
4   20:23.9 10:26.6
5   10:18.2 46:50.2
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Each make and version of database server has its own dialect of SQL. Please [edit] your question to add a [tag](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database you actually use. [tag:postgresql]? [tag:mysql]? Delete the other tags.

Comment: I think, I have done the same, thank you.